# Prove the direct sum of modules is isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, module-isomorphism

Suppose that $M_1$, $M_2$, $N_1$, $N_2$ are $R$-module and $M_1\cong N_1$, $M_2\cong N_2$. Prove that $M_1\oplus M_2\cong N_1\oplus N_2$.

I know that

$M_1\cong N_1$ imply there exist an isomorphism $\phi_1:M_1\to N_1$.

$M_2\cong N_2$ imply there exist an isomorphism $\phi_2:M_2\to N_2$.

To prove $M_1\oplus M_2\cong N_1\oplus N_2$, it should be prove there exist an isomorphism $\phi:M_1\oplus M_2\to N_1\oplus N_2$.

I confuse to find there exist an isomorphism $\phi:M_1\oplus M_2\to N_1\oplus N_2$. Is it true that $M_1\oplus M_2=M_1+M_2$? and what the hint to prove this problem?

Comment: How do you define $M_1 \oplus M_2$?

Comment: $M_1\oplus M_2$ is the direct sum of $M_1$ and $M_2$.

Comment: I know it's the direct sum. Answering your question depends on what definition you start with. Is it the product or coproduct? Is it defined element-wise or categorically? And so on.

Comment: In the book, it is not written what the definition of $M_1\oplus M_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define:
$$\phi:M_1 \oplus M_2 \to N_1 \oplus N_2$$
$$\phi(m_1,m_2)=(\phi_1(m_1),\phi_2(m_2))$$
And use their properties.